# HTML Side by Side div in div container

Tags: html

I am having some trouble with DIVs in regards to laying them side by side. An image will help.

I need to have the red box (or anything else i like) into the green outlined area. I want to try avoid things like float:left; since it ruins the formatting of the navigation bar.

I have tried using span tags around the navigation bar, using a specific amount of pixels to the left (which didn't work, and I don't like doing that anyway).

Please keep in mind I'm a beginner and therefore inexperienced.

> http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/12/webjd.jpg/

```
html:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<link href="navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <img id="header" alt="Banner" longdesc="Text Here" src="rsc/banner_phone.jpg"/>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="current"><a href=""><em class="home"></em><b>Homepage</b></a></li><br /><br />
                <li><a href=""><em class="templates">           </em><b>Homepage</b></a></li><br /><br />
                <li><a href="d"><em class="psd">                </em><b>Homepage</b></a></li><br /><br />
                <li><a href=""><em class="tutorials">           </em><b>Homepage</b></a></li><br /><br />
                <li><a href=""><em class="shop">                </em><b>Homepage</b></a></li><br /><br />
                <li><a href=""><em class="contact">             </em><b>Homepage</b></a></li><br /><br />
            </ul>                                       
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <p>sdfds</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>


</html>


css:

    /* PAGE CONTAINERS */
        /* Background Color */
    body {
        background:#CCCCCC
    }

    .page {
        width:80%;
        margin-left:10%;
        background-color:white;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000000;
    }

    .main {
        position:absolute;
        left:180px;
        background-color:red;
    }

    /* NAVIGATION ELEMENTS */

    #header {
    width:100%;
    height:185px;
    }

    .navigation {
        padding:3px 0 3px 0;
        margin:0;
        list-style:none;background-color:#DDDDDD;
    width:180px;
    height:100%;

        }

    .navigation li a {
        float:left;
        height:40px;
        line-height:40px;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
        padding:0 0 0 10px;
        font-size:11px;
    }
    .navigation li a b {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 20px 0 8px;
    }
    .navigation li.current a {
        color:#0000FF;
        font-weight: bold;
            font-size:13px;
    }
    .navigation li a:hover {
        color:#0000FF;
     padding: 0 0px 0 20px;
     }
    .navigation li a em {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:30px;
        height:40px;
    }

    /* ICON ELEMENTS */

    .navigation li a em.home {
        background-image: url(http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/css_navigation2/nav_icons/home.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    .navigation li a em.templates {
        background-image: url(http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/css_navigation2/nav_icons/templates.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    .navigation li a em.psd {
        background-image: url(http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/css_navigation2/nav_icons/psd.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    .navigation li a em.tutorials {
        background-image: url(http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/css_navigation2/nav_icons/tutorials.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    .navigation li a em.shop {
        background-image: url(http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/css_navigation2/nav_icons/shop.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    .navigation li a em.contact {
        background-image: url(http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/css_navigation2/nav_icons/contact.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add the css property as follows to the 2 `div's` you want to display on the same line:

```
display: inline-block;
```

So you would add this to the sidebar and the green box (in your image).

Remember though that this is not considered good practice.

Comment: Ah thank you, funny thing is i tried display inline, and display block before, even though i dont know what they do. I was desperate at this point. This worked. I just also had to align text to the top. tyvm. I'll be back if i have further issues.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, if you float:left properly with two divs both having the property, as long as they are within the other div container, they should not go out of bounds and ruin anything outside of that container, assuming that container can fit them. It is all about "overflow" and div size. To see whats going on better, I would suggest using firefox and getting an extension called firebug, it is invaluable in web development.